# authentification react js express

Tags: reactjs

I'm creating an authentication system in React and there's something I don't understand. There's my `fetchUser` action which is called twice in Redux DevTools. I show you my code:

**App component**

```
function App() 
{


   const [isAuth,setisAuth]=useState(false)
   const [isLoading,setIsLoading]=useState(true)
   
 
   const dispatch=useDispatch()
   useEffect(()=>{
         const token=localStorage.getItem('token')
         console.log("Dans useEffect")
         async function getUser(){
               try {

                   await dispatch(fetchUser())
                   setisAuth(true) 
                   setIsLoading(false)

               } catch (error)  { 
                  console.log(error)
                  //setIsLoading(false)
                  return
               }
         }
   
         token? getUser():setIsLoading(false)

   },[dispatch])

 function Relog(arg){
   setisAuth(arg)
 }

 if(isLoading){
    return <div className="container d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center" style={{height:'90vh'}}>
            {   console.log('Je suis dans mon rendu loading')}
            <Loading/>
           </div>
 }

  return (
    <authContext.Provider value={{isAuth,Relog}}>
       {   console.log('Je suis dans mon rendu App')}
      <Router >
       
         <Header/> 
         <Switch>
               <Route exact path='/' component={MovieList}/>
               <Route exact path='/movie/:movieId' component={MovieDetail}/>
               <PrivateRoute exact path='/favoris' component={FavoriteList}/>
               <Route exact path='/search' component={SearchResult}/>
               <Route exact path='/signin' component={Auth}/>
               <Route exact path='/test' component={Test}/>
               <Route component={PageNotFound}/>
         </Switch>
      </Router>
   </authContext.Provider>
    
  );
}


export default App;
```

**My action that calls the reducer**

```
export function fetchUser(){
    console.log('Fectch user action')
    return async(dispatch)=>{
       try 
       {
            const res=await fetch(`http://127.0.0.1:5000/api/auth/verify`,{
                headers:{
                    'Authorization':`Bearer ${localStorage.getItem('token')}`
                },
                method:'get'
            })
            const data=await res.json()
            if(data.error) throw data.error
         // console.log(data)
           dispatch({type:FETCH_USER,payload:data.user})
       } catch (error) {
          //  console.log(error)
           throw error
       }
    }
}
```

**Enpoint which checks if the token is good and returns user info**

```
router.get('/verify',auth,(req,res)=>{
  return res.status(200).json({user:req.user})
})
```

**Here is my authentication middleware**

```
module.exports = async(req, res, next) => {
   try {
       const header=req.headers.authorization;
       if(!header) return res.status(401).json({error:{message:"Erreur d'authentification,Veuillez vous connecter"}})
       const token =  header.split(' ')[1];
       const decodedToken = jwt.verify(token, process.env.SECRET);
       const user=await User.findByPk(decodedToken.userId)
       if(!user) throw new Err('Erreur d\'authentification',404)
       if(user.blocked) throw new Err('Votre compte est inactif pour le moment',404)
       req.user=user
       req.auth = {...decodedToken};
    
       next();
   } catch(error) 
   {
        if(error instanceof jwt.JsonWebTokenError) return res.status(401).json({error:{message:error.message}});
        next(error)

   }
};
```

I tried to remove all dependencies from `useEffect`, but the problem persists.

Comment: Do you have `StrictMode` inside your `index.js`?

Comment: no i did not use strict mode

Comment: I was gonna suggest you to remove the `dispatch` dependency and wrap it in a `useCallback` hook, but that would be redundant as this [issue](https://github.com/reduxjs/react-redux/issues/1468#issuecomment-651498880) reminded me that `dispatch` function reference survives during re-renders. I'd say you post your `index.js`. `StrictMode` is not something you use, it comes by default from React and you decide to remove it or not. As a last resort the issue could be with your own Redux DevTools configurations.

Comment: but the other actions are logged once in redux devTools